# Calculate difference between values in consecutive rows by group

Tags: r

This is a my `df` (data.frame):

```
group value
1     10
1     20
1     25
2     5
2     10
2     15
```

I need to calculate difference between values in consecutive rows by group.

So, I need a that result.

```
group value diff
1     10    NA # because there is a no previous value
1     20    10 # value[2] - value[1]
1     25    5  # value[3] value[2]
2     5     NA # because group is changed
2     10    5  # value[5] - value[4]
2     15    5  # value[6] - value[5]
```

Although, I can handle this problem by using `ddply`, but it takes too much time. This is because I have a lot of groups in my `df`. (over 1,000,000 groups in my `df`)

Are there any other effective approaches to handle this problem?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The package `data.table` can do this fairly quickly, using the `shift` function.

```
require(data.table)
df <- data.table(group = rep(c(1, 2), each = 3), value = c(10,20,25,5,10,15))
#setDT(df) #if df is already a data frame

df[ , diff := value - shift(value), by = group]    
#   group value diff
#1:     1    10   NA
#2:     1    20   10
#3:     1    25    5
#4:     2     5   NA
#5:     2    10    5
#6:     2    15    5
setDF(df) #if you want to convert back to old data.frame syntax
```

---

Or using the `lag` function in `dplyr`

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(Diff = value - lag(value))
#   group value  Diff
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    10    NA
# 2     1    20    10
# 3     1    25     5
# 4     2     5    NA
# 5     2    10     5
# 6     2    15     5
```

---

For alternatives pre-`data.table::shift` and pre-`dplyr::lag`, see edits.

Comment: Any chance you know a ddply solution?  I had been working at this for a while before I reasoned that might need a different function. . .

Comment: I assume it would be something like `ddply(df, .(group), transform, diff=c(NA,diff(value)))`

Comment: how can you modify this to calculate percentage change?

Comment: You could apply any function here. For example, if this is our function: `perc_change <- function(x, y) { return(x/y*100) }`, then we could call it like `df[ , perc_diff := perc_change(value, shift(value)), by = group]`

Comment: How can you substitute the NA to the next value so `Diff` for row 1 will also be `10` as it is for row 2?

Comment: @ManasiShah:     `library(dplyr)`, line 2:
`df$Diff <- as.data.frame((df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(Diff = value - lag(value)))[ , 3])` line 3:
`df$Diff[is.na(df$Diff)] <- unlist((df %>% group_by(group) %>%summarise(start.values = first(value)))[ , 2])`

Answer (score 24):

You can use the base function `ave()` for this

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(c(1,2),each=3),value=c(10,20,25,5,10,15))
df$diff <- ave(df$value, factor(df$group), FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
```

which returns

```
  group value diff
1     1    10   NA
2     1    20   10
3     1    25    5
4     2     5   NA
5     2    10    5
6     2    15    5
```

Comment: Related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378946/calculating-time-difference-by-id    I found both threads to be helpful.  For dates, you can use this:    `df$diff <- ave(as.numeric(df$Datevalue), factor(df$group), FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))`  Also, you can switch the position of the NA if you want the last row in the group to have the NA instead.   `df$diff <- ave(as.numeric(df$Datevalue), factor(df$group), FUN=function(x) c(diff(x), NA))`

Answer (score 4):

try this with tapply

```
df$diff<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(df$value,df$group,FUN=function(x){ return (c(NA,diff(x)))})))
```

Comment: this is what I had to do: `df$diff <- unlist(tapply(df$value,df$group, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))`