# Find greater or smaller value by grouped variable using data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My source data has data corresponding to a few months, but of those, I only want to compare data from pre-specified months.

Here's my input data:

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Aug", "Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    Pipe = c(3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, NA, 5), Gp = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Month", 
"Pipe", "Gp"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, of the three months, I only want to compare the months specified by below variables.

```
 This_month_to_compare <- "Oct"
  Last_Month_to_compare <- "Aug"
```

Now, for given `two months` above and based on groupings `Gp`, I want to indicate whether `Pipe` value in `This_month_to_compare` is greater than that in `Last month to compare`. If one of the two `pipe` values don't exist, we will leave it blank.

Here's what the output looks like (manually created because I wasn't successful with the code)

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Aug", "Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    Pipe = c(3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, NA, 5), Gp = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Greater = c(NA, 
    TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Month", 
"Pipe", "Gp", "Greater"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

Month   Pipe    Gp  Greater Explanation
Aug      3      A           Ignore: Aug
Oct      4      A   TRUE    4 > 3 
Aug      5      B           Ignore: Aug
Oct      3      B   FALSE   3< 5
Sep      2      B           Ignore: Sep
Aug      1      C           Ignore: Aug
Oct      3      D           There is nothing to compare with
Oct      3      E   FALSE   3<4
Aug      4      E           Ignore: Aug
Oct             F           Cannot compare NA with 5
Aug      5      F           Ignore: Aug
```

I have manually added explanation above.

I did try to code, and here's my attempt:

```
mydfi<-data.table::as.data.table(mydfi)
  mydf<-mydfi
  #Method 1: Convert to Wide Format
  #Convert to wide format
  mydf<-data.table::dcast(mydf,Gp ~ Month, value.var = "Pipe")
  #Compare
  mydf$Growth<-mydf[[This_month_to_compare]]>mydf[[Last_Month_to_compare]]
  #Back to long format
  Melt_columns<-c("Aug","Oct","Sep")
  mydf<-data.table::melt(mydf, measure.vars =Melt_columns,variable.name = "Month", value.name = "Pipe")
  mydfo<-mydf[mydfi,on=c("Month","Gp","Pipe")]
  mydfo[Month!=This_month_to_compare,"Growth"]<-NA
```

**An update:** I was able to solve above problem by just adding a left join. I have updated my code above. However, I am looking for a solution on these lines: [Calculate difference between values in consecutive rows by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846547/calculate-difference-between-values-in-consecutive-rows-by-group)

The reason is that my actual data set is very big and doesn't permit joins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by two joins. The first one filters out the months to compare and orders them as required. Then the comparisions can be done. The second join appends the result to the original data frame.

```
library(data.table)
# Last_Month_to_compare, This_month_to_compare
months_to_compare <- c("Aug", "Oct")
mDT <- setDT(mydf)[
  # append row id column (to preserve original order)
  , rn := .I][
    # cross join of groups and months
    CJ(Gp = Gp, Month = months_to_compare, unique = TRUE), on = .(Gp, Month)][
      # groupwise comparison of the two months
      , Greater := Pipe > shift(Pipe), by = Gp][]
# appending result to original data frame by joining with intermediate result
mydf[mDT, on = .(rn), Greater := i.Greater][]
```

> ```
>     Month Pipe Gp rn Greater
>  1:   Aug    3  A  1      NA
>  2:   Oct    4  A  2    TRUE
>  3:   Aug    5  B  3      NA
>  4:   Oct    3  B  4   FALSE
>  5:   Sep    2  B  5      NA
>  6:   Aug    1  C  6      NA
>  7:   Oct    3  D  7      NA
>  8:   Oct    3  E  8   FALSE
>  9:   Aug    4  E  9      NA
> 10:   Oct   NA  F 10      NA
> 11:   Aug    5  F 11      NA
> ```

Note that the original order of `mydf` is preserved.

The intermediate result `mDT` looks like

> ```
>     Month Pipe Gp rn Greater
>  1:   Aug    3  A  1      NA
>  2:   Oct    4  A  2    TRUE
>  3:   Aug    5  B  3      NA
>  4:   Oct    3  B  4   FALSE
>  5:   Aug    1  C  6      NA
>  6:   Oct   NA  C NA      NA
>  7:   Aug   NA  D NA      NA
>  8:   Oct    3  D  7      NA
>  9:   Aug    4  E  9      NA
> 10:   Oct    3  E  8   FALSE
> 11:   Aug    5  F 11      NA
> 12:   Oct   NA  F 10      NA
> ```

#### Edit: Additional explanation

The OP has asked for an explanation of the difference between `mydf[mDT, on = .(rn)]` and `mydf[mDT, on = .(rn), Greater := i.Greater][]`.

With `data.table`, `X[Y, on = ...]` is a *right outer join* which is equivalent to `merge(X, Y, all.y = TRUE)`, i.e., it returns all rows of `Y` (see [JOINing data in R using data.table](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html)). So,

```
mydf[mDT, on = .(rn)]
```

returns

> ```
>     Month Pipe Gp rn i.Month i.Pipe i.Gp Greater
>  1:   Aug    3  A  1     Aug      3    A      NA
>  2:   Oct    4  A  2     Oct      4    A    TRUE
>  3:   Aug    5  B  3     Aug      5    B      NA
>  4:   Oct    3  B  4     Oct      3    B   FALSE
>  5:   Aug    1  C  6     Aug      1    C      NA
>  6:    NA   NA NA NA     Oct     NA    C      NA
>  7:    NA   NA NA NA     Aug     NA    D      NA
>  8:   Oct    3  D  7     Oct      3    D      NA
>  9:   Aug    4  E  9     Aug      4    E      NA
> 10:   Oct    3  E  8     Oct      3    E   FALSE
> 11:   Aug    5  F 11     Aug      5    F      NA
> 12:   Oct   NA  F 10     Oct     NA    F      NA
> ```

Columns prefixed by `i.` come from `mDT`. Note that rows 6 and 7 do not have matching rows in `mydf`. Also, the order of rows is determined by the order in `mDT`.

If `mydf` and `mDT` are interchanged,

```
mDT[mydf, on = .(rn)][]
```

returns

> ```
>     Month Pipe Gp rn Greater i.Month i.Pipe i.Gp
>  1:   Aug    3  A  1      NA     Aug      3    A
>  2:   Oct    4  A  2    TRUE     Oct      4    A
>  3:   Aug    5  B  3      NA     Aug      5    B
>  4:   Oct    3  B  4   FALSE     Oct      3    B
>  5:    NA   NA NA  5      NA     Sep      2    B
>  6:   Aug    1  C  6      NA     Aug      1    C
>  7:   Oct    3  D  7      NA     Oct      3    D
>  8:   Oct    3  E  8   FALSE     Oct      3    E
>  9:   Aug    4  E  9      NA     Aug      4    E
> 10:   Oct   NA  F 10      NA     Oct     NA    F
> 11:   Aug    5  F 11      NA     Aug      5    F
> ```

Columns prefixed by `i.` come from `mydf`, now. Note that row 5 has no match in `mDT`. Also, the order of rows is determined by `mydf`.

With the assignment operator `:=`, `X[Y, on = ..., a := b]` becomes a *left inner join* which includes all rows of `X` in its original order. Thus,

```
mydf[mDT, on = .(rn), Greater := i.Greater][]
```

returns

> ```
>     Month Pipe Gp rn Greater
>  1:   Aug    3  A  1      NA
>  2:   Oct    4  A  2    TRUE
>  3:   Aug    5  B  3      NA
>  4:   Oct    3  B  4   FALSE
>  5:   Sep    2  B  5      NA
>  6:   Aug    1  C  6      NA
>  7:   Oct    3  D  7      NA
>  8:   Oct    3  E  8   FALSE
>  9:   Aug    4  E  9      NA
> 10:   Oct   NA  F 10      NA
> 11:   Aug    5  F 11      NA
> ```

where `Greater` becomes `NA` for non-matching rows.

Comment: @Uwe- Thanks for your help. Could you please help me understand the difference between   `mydf[mDT, on = .(rn)][]` and `mydf[mDT, on = .(rn), Greater := i.Greater][]`. I understood what's going on with the former. It's a left join on `rn`, but I am unsure what `Greater := i.Greater` does. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are thinking of?

```
> library(data.table)
> mydf <- data.table(mydf)
> This_month_to_compare <- "Oct"
> Last_Month_to_compare <- "Aug"
> setkey(mydf, Gp, Month)
> 
> # Make dummy table to join with
> mydf[
+   , Pipe_this := .SD[Month == This_month_to_compare, Pipe], by = "Gp"][
+     , Pipe_last := .SD[Month == Last_Month_to_compare, Pipe], by = "Gp"][
+       , `:=`(
+         Greater = Pipe_last < Pipe_this, Pipe_last = NULL, Pipe_this = NULL)][
+           Month != "Oct", Greater := NA]
> mydf
    Month Pipe Gp Greater
 1:   Aug    3  A      NA
 2:   Oct    4  A    TRUE
 3:   Aug    5  B      NA
 4:   Oct    3  B   FALSE
 5:   Sep    2  B      NA
 6:   Aug    1  C      NA
 7:   Oct    3  D      NA
 8:   Aug    4  E      NA
 9:   Oct    3  E   FALSE
10:   Aug    5  F      NA
11:   Oct   NA  F      NA
```

You can simplify the code to avoid two of the `[.data.table` calls from the above if you want and avoid defining the `Pipe_this` and `Pipe_last`.