# Calculate a new column based on the difference between current row and previous row in another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

edit: My question is similar to [Calculate difference between values in consecutive rows by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846547), but for my purpose I need the first row to calculate the difference to 0 instead of returning NA.

I would like to add a new column to my dataframe that has the difference between the value of my "time" column in this row and the previous row.

Here is my sample data:

```
 my_data = data.frame(time = c(.5, .75, 1, .25, .5, 1), group = rep(c("dogs","cats"), each=3))
```

which gives:

```
  time group
1 0.50  dogs
2 0.75  dogs
3 1.00  dogs
4 0.25  cats
5 0.50  cats
6 1.00  cats
```

I now want a new variable called diff, that is computed separately for each group. When the row is the first row in each group, it should calculate the difference from 0.

```
  time group diff
1 0.50  dogs .5
2 0.75  dogs .25
3 1.00  dogs .25
4 0.25  cats .25
5 0.50  cats .25
6 1.00  cats .50
```

Comment: its duplicate question with slightly difference. The solution which can work is: `my_data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(diff = abs(time - lag(time, default = 0)))`

Comment: this works, that you!

Comment: From one of the answer in the marked duplicate : `ave(my_data$time, my_data$group, FUN=function(x) c(x[1],diff(x)))`