# calculating followup per id

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I'm trying to recalculate follow-up time in years for a medium size data frame (16000 rows 100 variables).

This has been partially asked here 
[Calculating time difference by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378946/calculating-time-difference-by-id) 
but what is described here is in essence what I want to do, but I don't have time only date available.

I would like to figure out why it does not work for only date.

when I run this code it works:

## generate data:

```
Incident.ID.. = c(rep("INCFI0000029582",4), rep("INCFI0000029587",4))
date = c("2014-09-25 08:39:45", "2014-09-25 08:39:48", "2014-09-25 08:40:44", "2014-10-10 23:04:00", "2014-09-25 08:33:32", "2014-09-25 08:34:41", "2014-09-25 08:35:24", "2014-10-10 23:04:00")
df = data.frame(Incident.ID..,date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## run code

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(Incident.ID..) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(0, diff(ymd_hms(date))))
```

## output

```
  Incident.ID..   date                    diff
  <chr>           <chr>                  <dbl>
1 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-25 08:39:45       0.
2 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-25 08:39:48       3.
3 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-25 08:40:44      56.
4 INCFI0000029582 2014-10-10 23:04:00 1347796.
5 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-25 08:33:32       0.
6 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-25 08:34:41      69.
7 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-25 08:35:24      43.
8 INCFI0000029587 2014-10-10 23:04:00 1348116.
```

my data has a YMD format so this seemed logical:

## generate data

```
Incident.ID.. = c(rep("INCFI0000029582",4), rep("INCFI0000029587",4))
date = c("2014-09-20", "2014-09-21", "2014-09-22", "2014-09-23", "2014-09-26", "2014-09-27", "2014-09-28", "2014-10-10")
df = data.frame(Incident.ID..,date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## run code

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(Incident.ID..) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(0, diff(ymd(date))))
```

## output

```
  Incident.ID..   date        diff
  <chr>           <chr>      <dbl>
1 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-20    0.
2 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-21    1.
3 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-22    1.
4 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-23    1.
5 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-26    0.
6 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-27    1.
7 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-28    1.
8 INCFI0000029587 2014-10-10   12.
```

it now gives differences between subsequent observations instead of the first Incident.ID..

an answer was given here: [Date difference per ID with dplyr without hours, minutes or seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284810/date-difference-per-id-with-dplyr-without-hours-minutes-or-seconds) but I still don't understand WHY it does not work using this very similar code above. (any why it now gives the difference in days instead of seconds).

when using data table method I get the same result:

```
padded.diff = function(x) c(0L, diff(x)) 
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, date.diff := padded.diff(as.POSIXct(date)), by = Incident.ID..]
View(df)
```

Any explanation of this behaviour would be very welcome as it does not give a parsing error . (it probably has something to do with the posix time but I'm baffled)

Comment: Isn't your first example, using `ymd_hms`, also giving the difference between subsequent observations? Row 3 is row 2 + 56 seconds, not row 1 plus 56 seconds. The default `lag` for `diff` is 1.

Comment: @neilfws you are very right .I did not check adequately and I assumed the accepted answer was correct. That said, is there an more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it's the calling of different methods for the `diff` function depending on the class of what you're passing to it.

```
c("2014-09-20") %>% ymd() %>% class()
#    [1] "Date"

c("2014-09-25 08:39:45") %>% ymd_hms() %>% class()
#    [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

As such, passing an object of class `Date` to `diff` will provide you with days (through calling `diff.Date`), whereas passing an object of class `POSIXt` will provide you with seconds (`diff.POSIXt`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i wouldnt say it has something to do with classes.
my suggestion would be this.

```
Incident.ID.. = c(rep("INCFI0000029582",4), rep("INCFI0000029587",5)) 
#changing second rep from 4 to 5
date = c("2014-09-20", "2014-09-21", "2014-09-22", "2014-09-23", "2014-09-26", "2014-09-27", "2014-09-28", "2014-10-10", "2014-10-10 00:00:01") 
#adding one more timeframe right after the last one
df = data.frame(Incident.ID..,date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

padded.diff = function(x) c(0L, diff(x)) 
df2=within(df, {
date.diff   = ave(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date)), Incident.ID.., FUN = padded.diff) })
df2 = df2[-nrow(df2),]

df2
Incident.ID..       date date.diff
1 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-20         0
2 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-21     86400
3 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-22     86400
4 INCFI0000029582 2014-09-23     86400
5 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-26         0
6 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-27     86400
7 INCFI0000029587 2014-09-28     86400
8 INCFI0000029587 2014-10-10   1036800
```

my guess is that it displaying days and not seconds is some form of truncating. So I add one element more with a change of 1 second in order to force displaying in seconds.

or just use the knowladge of 1 day containing 86400 seconds.